# How to put a .podspec file in different repo

Tags: git, cocoapods

I need to put my code project in a github repo, for example

> https://github.com/myName/myProject
>   (this is done already)

but I need to put the specs for it in another repo, because my company already has the specs for several other repos published here

> https://github.com/myName/myPodspecs
>   There are folders for each of the other projects inside this repo like ProjectA/2.5.0/ProjectA.podspec

I don't understand how to direct the .podspec file to the other repo (myPodspecs). I don't understand how to do create a new folder in the myPodspecs folder. I've tried `podspec create myProject https://github.com/myName/myPodspecs` but that doesn't seem to work properly, it just duplicates the current group of podspecs inside of a new folder (in ~/.cocoapods/repos).

I have the `myProject.podspec` file in the myProject folder.

Comment: If I understood correctly: in the .podspec you can give the link from where to get the sources files. I don't understood why you want to do so, because usually a pod spec is where the source code is (except for downloaded stuff), but it should work. In the pod file, you can specify the URL of a podpsec (which might be different from the sources).

Comment: Sure, but in this case our company has set up a separate repo for *just* the podspecs. I'm not the originator of that system so I can not change it.

Comment: So in the `podspecs`, there is a `source` attribute that should redirect through the correct git url and paths for the sources. If you look at the `podspec` of AFNetworking, there is `s.source   = { :git =>...}`  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking.podspec

Answer (score 0):

The source attribute in the podspec points to the location of the pod source. It does not have to be in the same github repo.

Here is an [example repo with a podspec pointing to another repo](https://github.com/firebase/leveldb-library-podspec).